# Custom UISlider behaving different on iOS 4.3 and iOS 5

Tags: ios5, uislider

I have some sliders in my app that are customized using setMinimumTrackImage:forState: and setMaximumTrackImage:forState:

On iOS 4.3 devices they show up exactly how I want them to look, but when running on iOS 5 devices the textures are being stretched incorrectly.

Is this a known issue? Did something about UISliders change in the iOS 5 update?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem before where the track images always show up okay in iOS 4 but not in iOS 5. I tried to make the images resizable. And it worked for me. Please try this:

```
UIImage *leftTrackImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"progress_left.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 0)];
UIImage *rightTrackImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"progress_right.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 0)];
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use stretchableImageWithLeftCat:TopCap: ?